# jsnlog producing errors on install

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, jsnlog

I am having some issues installing and using jsnlog as described on [the docs](http://jsnlog.com/Documentation/HowTo/Angular2Logging). I keep getting errors when I try to import or use the library.

I tried to import the library as in the docs:

`import { JL } from 'jsnlog'`

I also tried including it this way (don't what this style is called)

`import 'jsnlog';`

The errors I get in the console when I run `npm run serve` are:

```
ERROR in C:\Users\jeanpierreb\Documents\project\node_modules\jsnlog\Definitions\jl.d.ts
(279,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'r'.

ERROR in C:\Users\jeanpierreb\Documents\project\node_modules\jsnlog\Definitions\jl.d.ts
(279,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 't'.

ERROR in C:\Users\jeanpierreb\Documents\project\node_modules\jsnlog\Definitions\jl.d.ts
(279,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'J'.

ERROR in C:\Users\jeanpierreb\Documents\project\node_modules\jsnlog\Definitions\jl.d.ts
(279,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'L'.

ERROR in ./app_ts/app.module.ts
(4,21): error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/jeanpierreb/Documents/project\node_modules/jsnlog/Definitions/jl.d.ts' is not a module.
```

**Software Versions**
I'm including the node/npm/angular versions because I have a feeling the issue may be here. I haven't tried this on other versions of node other than the most recent, but this is a rather large project so I can't readily upgrade npm or node without breaking the app

- Angular 2.1.1
- npm 4.6.1
- node 6.10.3

For completeness here is my tsconfig and package.json

**package.json**

```
  {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "myproject",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings",
    "build": "webpack --progress",
    "build-prod": "webpack -p --progress --env.prod",
    "serve": "webpack --progress --colors --watch",
    "start": "lite-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.1.1",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.2",
    "@types/handlebars": "4.0.32",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/signalr": "^2.0.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "devextreme": "16.2.3",
    "devextreme-angular": "16.2.3-rc.3",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "jsnlog": "^2.24.0",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "jszip": "3.1.3",
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.6",
    "ng2-vis": "0.0.5",
    "node-sass": "4.5.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.2",
    "scss-compile": "0.1.7",
    "signalr": "2.2.1",
    "style-loader": "0.13.2",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.1",
    "uglify-js": "2.8.13",
    "vis": "4.18.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "0.3.2",
    "css-loader": "0.26.2",
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "source-map-loader": "0.1.6",
    "style-loader": "0.13.2",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.1",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "typings": "2.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "0.3.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app",
    "rootDir": "app"


  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot/node_modules",    
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "typings/globals/index.d.ts",
    "typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `ts-loader` in your webpack config, for some reason `ts-loader` doesn't compile `jsnlog` correctly by replacing `ts-loader` with `awesome-typescript-loader` will solve the problem.